# Fedora can't find libSDL2main.so (and doesn't need it): can I use one Makefile for Fedora and Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, sdl-2, yum

On Fedora, my command `g++ main.cpp` sdl2-config --cflags `-lSDL2main -lSDL2` thinks that the `SLD2main` library is not available. It's right: other SDL2 libraries are in `/usr/lib64`; `libSDL2main.so` is not.

But I installed all apparently relevant SDL2 rpm's. Here's what the system tells me when I say `yum install SDL2`:

```
Package SDL2-2.0.12-1.fc32.x86_64 is already installed.
Package SDL2-devel-2.0.12-1.fc32.x86_64 is already installed.
Package SDL2_image-2.0.5-3.fc32.x86_64 is already installed.
Package SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-3.fc32.x86_64 is already installed.
Package SDL2_mixer-2.0.4-5.fc32.x86_64 is already installed.
Package SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-5.fc32.x86_64 is already installed.
Package SDL2_ttf-2.0.15-4.fc32.x86_64 is already installed.
Package SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-4.fc32.x86_64 is already installed.
```

If I take the g++ option `-lSDL2main` out, the program links and runs.

But this is a problem. I want my Makefile to work on Unix systems generally. How can I do this -- use the same Makefile for RedHat/Fedora and Debian/Ubuntu?

Comment: You don't need `SDL2main` on any desktop unix system, here it just contains one empty function that is never called; it exists only for compatibility reasons. And it is never a dynamic library, look for `libSDL2main.a`, not `.so`. Just don't link with it unless you're on system where it may be useful (windows, android, ios).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting the linker flags from `sdl2-config --libs`, or `pkg-config sdl2 --libs`.

Comment: Yes! Missed that somehow.